# How to get list of payment gatways in DocuSign account.?

Tags: docusignapi

I am working on DocuSign Payment integration. How to get the list of payment gateways that associated to the account?

I tried with the [docusign rest api](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Payments/PaymentGatewayAccounts/list/#/definitions/paymentGatewayAccountsInfo), but getting following error with the status code 404.

> {
>       "errorCode": "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
>       "message": "The URL provided does not resolve to a resource."
>   }

Comment: Please show us the URL you are posting to. If you post to the correct endpoint it should return the Payment Gateways.

Comment: URL: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/3037348/payment_gateway_accounts

Comment: Can you use the DocuSign web tool to make a test payment? Maybe your account isn't enabled for payments.

Comment: Payment success with hard coded gateway id.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your get request is in this format.

```
GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{AccountId}/payment_gateway_accounts
```

Comment: URL: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/3037348/payment_gateway_accounts

Comment: Header : {"Authorization": "Bearer Access_token"}

Comment: Are you facing issue with only this endPoint? Are you able to make calls to other endPoints using the Authorization header?

Comment: All other rest API's are working fine with the same autherization header

Comment: This might be a bug with the DocuSign Api. I will pass this information to our development team.

Answer (score 0):

I have verified the problem with

```
GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{AccountId}/payment_gateway_accounts
```

and have submitted DocuSign internal bug id API-7063.

I am sorry that this is causing a problem for you.

---

## Workaround

I suggest hardcoding the information for now. You can retrieve the gateway account Id using the following steps.

- Goto to docusign admin
- Click on Payments
- Get the gateway account ID from the table of connected gateway accounts that is displayed there.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Payment working fine with hardcoded gateway id, But in our production server, hard coding is not possible because we must provide end user to select their gateway in our system.

Comment: Is the issue fixed?

Comment: Our team has worked on a fix for this issue. It will be live during the first week of September. Meanwhile please use the workaround suggested in the answer.