# DocuSign Payment gateway listing rest API not working

Tags: docusignapi

DocuSign payment geteway rest API not working in demo enviornment.
I tried with the [documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Payments/PaymentGatewayAccounts/list/#/definitions/PaymentGatewayAccounts). But getting the error like following:

> { "errorCode": "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND", "message": "The URL provided does not resolve to a resource." }

Comment: This is a bug with the DocuSign api. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44716425/1219543)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get list of payment gatways in DocuSign account.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691547/how-to-get-list-of-payment-gatways-in-docusign-account)

Comment: @CodingDawg I want to select gateway account dynamically when creating an envelop with payment tab. Is there any other api to get list of payment gateway? . Or when will fix this issue?

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691547/how-to-get-list-of-payment-gatways-in-docusign-account